# How to create/edit an xml using ant script?

Tags: ant

We use webmethods to develop our projects. I'm executing jcode batch file using  tag. the manifest file should be in xml format. But ant gives manifest in text format,where the field names and values are separated by colon. So I wanted to know is there a way to create manifest file in xml format. Appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [`<echoxml>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoxml.html) task that can be used to create a file in XML format. Ant automatically creates a `MANIFEST.MF` file when you use the `<jar>`, `<war>`, or `<ear>` task. I'm not sure what Ant would do if you specify a `MANIFEST.MF` file in XML format. I believe it will still modify it and the results won't be pretty.

However, you can use the `<zip>` task which is what the `<jar>` and other related tasks are based upon. The `<zip>` doesn't require a `MANIFEST.MF` file, so you can use whatever one you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [xslt](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html) transform. Ant can support XSLT 2.0 easily with the [saxon processor](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/).